# IIS url 404's when it contains 'as' with no extension

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm having an odd issue.

IIS 7 throws a 404 when trying to access url 'www.MYURL.co.za/dc/Fred.Basset'

We're handling the Fred.Basset part in the global.asax, but IIS is not even letting the request through.

I've managed to get it down to the 'as' being the issue - ie 'www.MYURL.co.za/dc/as' throws the 404.

If I give the url an extension (e.g.www.MYURL.co.za/dc/as.txt) I don't get the IIS 404 and it reaches the global.asax

I have no filters on IIS and nothing I can see that would cause this.

I've tried a URL Rewrite, but that only works if 'as' is not in the link.

Comment: Just to be complete, does a URL of 'www.MYURL.co.za/dc/Fred.Bosset' (replaced "as" with "os") work? Do you have any routes set up?

Comment: if i replace 'as' with 'os' it works. The only IIS bindings I have are http:*:80, which is standard in IIS. It's not getting through to my ASP.NET routes.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in isolation? Ensure that it is IIS causing this issue?

Comment: If i attempt it local, it works - hit's the global.asax and get's routed accordingly. Issue occurs only when attempting to run on my production or testing servers.

Comment: I would look in the HandlerMappings section of the IIS Manager on the production/testing servers. Your IT might have put some interesting wildcard mappings such as *.*as* to the asp.net ISAPI dlls which would then try to find a matching file name on disk rather.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL rewrite was the issue - IT added a command to block certain file extensions, but it was blocking all occurences of those strings instead of just extensions

Answer (score 0):

Classic mode and Integrated mode problem
if use mvc on iis 7 
select Integrated mode for iis

Comment: Not using MVC on this project.